# "In the next years to come" or "In the years to come"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I want to write a sentence saying that I hope that something will still happen in the following years. Which is the best way to write it ?

I would like to keep doing that in the years to come.

OR

I would like to keep doing that in the next years to come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*In the years to come*.

What might *in the next years to come* mean? (Is it intended to be in opposition to *in the previous years to come*?)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to still be doing that in years to come.

Comment: Please visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help), particularly those sections on crafting good answers. Answers on this site and elsewhere in the SE network are expected to provide detailed explanations, including any appropriate references.